# SCSI error: return code = 0x08000002, sense key: Aborted Command

Tags: software-raid, raid1, scsi, smart, dmraid

The kernel logs:

```
ata2.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x7fffffff SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata2.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
ata2.00: cmd 61/08:f0:6f:5b:97/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 30 ncq 4096 out
         res 41/10:01:6f:5b:97/d5:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x481 (invalid argument) <F>
ata2.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata2.00: error: { IDNF }
ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
sd 1:0:0:0: SCSI error: return code = 0x08000002
sdb: Current [descriptor]: sense key: Aborted Command
    Add. Sense: Recorded entity not found

Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
        72 0b 14 00 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
        00 97 5b 6f 
end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 9919343
ata2: EH complete
SCSI device sdb: 625142448 512-byte hdwr sectors (320073 MB)
sdb: Write Protect is off
sdb: Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
SCSI device sdb: drive cache: write through
SCSI device sdb: 625142448 512-byte hdwr sectors (320073 MB)
sdb: Write Protect is off
sdb: Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
SCSI device sdb: drive cache: write through
```

SCSI error codes were explained [here](http://www.novell.com/support/dynamickc.do?cmd=show&forward=nonthreadedKC&docType=kc&externalId=7006510&sliceId=1).

According to the [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/152855/sata-hdd-errors) topic, below is the `smartctl` result:

```
smartctl version 5.38 [x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu] Copyright (C) 2002-8 Bruce Allen
Home page is http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     WDC WD3202ABYS-01B7A0
Serial Number:    WD-WCAT18587154
Firmware Version: 02.03B02
User Capacity:    320,072,933,376 bytes
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  Exact ATA specification draft version not indicated
Local Time is:    Thu Sep  8 12:40:41 2011 ICT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x84) Offline data collection activity
                    was suspended by an interrupting command from host.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:         (6180) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  75) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x303f) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   200   200   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       975
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       20
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   076   076   000    Old_age   Always       -       17927
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       19
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       16
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       20
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   114   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       29
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]


SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

This server is running software RAID-1:

```
# dmraid -s -s
*** Group superset .ddf1_disks
--> Active Subset
name   : xx
size   : 624737792
stride : 128
type   : mirror
status : ok
subsets: 0
devs   : 2
spares : 0
```

Should I replace this device?

---

**UPDATE**

Short and long self-test reports no errors:

```
# smartctl -l selftest /dev/sdb
smartctl version 5.38 [x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu] Copyright (C) 2002-8 Bruce Allen
Home page is http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     17930         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     17929         -
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** - the disk says "recorded entity not found", so it does not find something on disk which should be there. Sounds like low-level formatting is no longer intact. It may be corrected by now, but it happened for a reason.

This drive is not relaiable anymore.